# JPA repository does not make delete request

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "SOME_TABLE_NAME")
@IdClass(ExpertAndRequestId.class)
public class ExpertAndRequest implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long managerId;

    @Id
    private Long requestId;

    private String comment;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "managerId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    //@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Manager manager;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "requestId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ParticipantRequest request;

    @PreRemove
    public void preRemove(){
        // THIS METHOD EXECUTED
    }

}
```

When I execute

```
this.expertAndRequestRepository.delete(request);
```

The method marked with @PreRemove annotation is called, but hibernate does not execute the query. In the logs there is no sql query to delete...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any error logs??

Comment: @Afridi nothing..(

Comment: is `ExpertAndRequestRepository.delete` a static method?

Comment: no, I misspelled it. Fixed the issue

Comment: Are you triggering a flush either explicitly or implicitly by committing the transaction?